# This code for binary output does not work properly - Assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

in the code below, i am trying to push a value to jump binary which will then be displayed as binary code. For some reason the code seems to only display 1111 instead of dividing properly and showing the respective binary code for each decimal number in count. Any advice guys?

```
CURSOR  MACRO Col, Row
    MOV AH,02
    MOV BH,00
    MOV DL,Col
    MOV DH,Row
    INT 10H
  ENDM

DISP   MACRO MES
    MOV AH,09
    MOV DX,OFFSET MES
    INT 21H

.DATA
.
.
.

N1              DB      '1','$'  
N2              DB      '2','$'
N3              DB      '3','$'
N4              DB      '4','$'
N5              DB      '5','$'
N6              DB      '6','$'
N7              DB      '7','$'
N8              DB      '8','$'
N9              DB      '9','$'
COUNT           DB      0


.
.
.code
. 
.
.
.
MOV COUNT,5
.
.
BINARY: MOV AL,COUNT; 22,39 38 37 36
        CBW
        DIV TWO

        CURSOR 36,22
        CMP AH,0
        JE ZERO
        JNE ONE
ZERO:   DISP N0
        jmp x
ONE:    DISP N1
x:      
        CBW         
        DIV TWO

        CURSOR 35,22
        CMP AH,0
        JE ZERO1
        JNE ONE1
ZERO1:   DISP N0
        jmp x1
ONE1:    DISP N1
x1:      
        CBW         
        DIV TWO

        CURSOR 34,22
        CMP AH,0
        JE ZERO2
        JNE ONE2
ZERO2:   DISP N0
        jmp x2
ONE2:    DISP N1
x2:      
        CBW         
        DIV TWO

        CURSOR 33,22
        CMP AH,0
        JE ZERO3
        JNE ONE3
ZERO3:   DISP N0
        jmp x3
ONE3:    DISP N1
x3:      
        JMP L0
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour and draw, on paper, what happens during each step of the process, e.g. to AL and AH. Show the single bits. That will probably make you see what is wrong.

Comment: When you post code that isn't working, you should post the _complete, minimal_ code necessary to reproduce the problem. The code you've posted appears to be missing several things, like `DISP`, `N1` and `N2`. Also, what are those stray dots at the beginning of the code?

Comment: I guess the stray dots represent the code that was left out.

Comment: What are the `CURSOR` and `DISP` instructions? How do they affect `AH` which you assume still carries a meaningful value?

Comment: thanks guys, edited the code to make it easier, will be making a flowchart later tonight :)

Comment: People on this forum are not going to like that you changed the above post with code that no longer reflects the original question. You should restore the above post and then post a different question.

Comment: ok ill change it back to how it was, thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some pointers to get you on your way.

1. The `MOV COUNT,5` instruction is placed between the data and so probably a reason to malfunction.
2. Each time you use `DIV N2` you divide by 50 because *N2* was defined as a character. Best also define a number 2 with `TWO db 2`
3. When you want to compare the remainder of the division you already have destroyed the AH register through the macro call `CURSOR 39,22`
4. The second time you use `DIV N2` the AX register no longer contain a usable value because the macro calls `DISP N0` and `DISP N1` have put the number 09h in the AH register.
5. To succesfully do a cascade of 4 divisions you must preserve the quotient of each previous division and then use that as the dividend for the following division. See example below.
6. When you use `DISP N0` to display "0" I think that you need to jump over the instruction `DISP N1` because now you are getting both "01".

An easy solution for problems 3 and 4 would be to save at least the AX register in both macros.

```
CURSOR  MACRO Col, Row
push ax
MOV AH,02
MOV BH,00
MOV DL,Col
MOV DH,Row
INT 10H
pop ax
ENDM

DISP   MACRO MES
push ax
MOV AH,09
MOV DX,OFFSET MES
INT 21H
pop ax
ENDM
```

Solution to the cascade (to be repeated for each division):

```
BINARY: MOV AL,COUNT; 22,39 38 37 36
        CBW
        DIV TWO
        push ax     ;Save the quotient in AL
        CURSOR 39,22
        CMP AH,0
        JE ZERO
        JNE ONE
ZERO:   DISP N0
        jmp x
ONE:    DISP N1
x:      pop ax      ;Restore the quotient in AL
        cbw         ;Extent before byte division
        DIV TWO
```

Comment: thanks for the advice my friend, i will implement this and report back soon. As for the first problem, that was editing mistake on my part, mov count,5 is in the code, not the date segment.  i will implement solutions to problems 2,3,4 and get back to you :)

Comment: i fixed the program the way you suggested but now im getting an overflow problem when it dives ah by "two" . I added the command CBW after each DIV TWO but is still says overflow. Exact error given by emu8086: divide - overflow - to manually process this error change address of INT 0 in interrupt vector table.. Any advice guys?

Comment: You should surely not add `CBW` __after__ the `DIV TWO` but rather before. Also be absolutely sure that _TWO_ is defined as a __byte sized__ variable.

Comment: ill definetely try this and get back to you guys, on a side note; if i made an array and stored the remainders in that array, wouldnt it make things easier? and then just print the array backward, that would solve mostly everything.

Comment: it works perfectly! thanks a lot man <3 I am going to mark your reply as the answer fifoernik , thanks a lot for helping me. If you don't mind, ill keep replying to this thread for one more day, im going to attempt to change the code a bit so that the binary values can be saved into an array and can be used later like when sending signal through a 7447 ic chip connected to a 7 segment LED

Answer (score 0):

```
    CURSOR  MACRO Col, Row
push ax
MOV AH,02
MOV BH,00
MOV DL,Col
MOV DH,Row
INT 10H
pop ax
ENDM

DISP   MACRO MES
push ax
MOV AH,09
MOV DX,OFFSET MES
INT 21H
pop ax
ENDM


.DATA
.
.
.

N1              DB      '1','$'  
N2              DB      '2','$'
N3              DB      '3','$'
N4              DB      '4','$'
N5              DB      '5','$'
N6              DB      '6','$'
N7              DB      '7','$'
N8              DB      '8','$'
N9              DB      '9','$'
COUNT           DB      0
TWO             DB      2
STR1            DB      4 DUP('$')

.
.
.code
. 
.
.
.
MOV COUNT,5
.
.
BINARY: MOV AL,COUNT; 22,39 38 37 36
        CBW
        DIV TWO
        push ax     ;Save the quotient in AL
        CURSOR 36,22
        CMP AH,0
        JE ZERO
        JNE ONE
ZERO:   DISP N0
        jmp x
ONE:    DISP N1
x:      pop ax      ;Restore the quotient in AL
        CBW         ;Extent before byte division
        DIV TWO
        push ax     ;Save the quotient in AL
        CURSOR 35,22
        CMP AH,0
        JE ZERO1
        JNE ONE1
ZERO1:   DISP N0
        jmp x1
ONE1:    DISP N1
x1:      pop ax      ;Restore the quotient in AL
        CBW         ;Extent before byte division
        DIV TWO
        push ax     ;Save the quotient in AL
        CURSOR 34,22
        CMP AH,0
        JE ZERO2
        JNE ONE2
ZERO2:   DISP N0
        jmp x2
ONE2:    DISP N1
x2:      pop ax      ;Restore the quotient in AL
        CBW         ;Extent before byte division
        DIV TWO
        push ax     ;Save the quotient in AL
        CURSOR 33,22
        CMP AH,0
        JE ZERO3
        JNE ONE3
ZERO3:   DISP N0
        jmp x3
ONE3:    DISP N1
x3:      pop ax      ;Restore the quotient in AL
        JMP L0
```